# Ansible "missing sudo password" even with passwordless sudo enabled

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, sudo

I have in my sudoers file

```
ALL            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Which allows anyone to use sudo without entering a password.  And I confirmed that I can sudo without a password when I ssh into the machine.

Yet when I attempt to run a playbook on it, I get an error "missing sudo password".

The command I'm using to run is

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml common_install.yaml --limit vpn.lan.example.com -vvv
```

I've run the same command, limiting it to a different host, that has the same sudo rule, and are both running Ubuntu 20.04, and it works on that.  But won't work on this host.

Why won't it work?

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Add to your question the parsed sudo commands, the output of `ansible -i inventory.yaml  -m command -a "sudo --list" --limit vpn.lan.example.com `   
 sudo config can be non-trivial, loading various files and even from ldap if configured, not to mention being sure to check the correct user on the correct host.

Comment: have you tried setting ansible_become_password as an emtpy string in the inventory file

Answer (score 2):

It is possible you have not populated the group_vars or host_vars directory(s) with the username and password values/files.

An example of a group_vars dir:

nodes.yml

```
ansible_port: 22
ansible_user: username
ansible_password: password
ansible_connection: ssh
ansible_become_pass: otherPassword
```

Note: the variables in the group_vars/host_vars directory(s) contain files with **variables only** do not include the `vars:` keyword, or your other variables will be ignored.